# How to pass input values as arguments into the custom filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass two argument to the custom filter '**from'** and **'to'** into the custom filter I have created in my controller.

Here you can see my custom filter I have created:

```
    vm.filterMinutes = function (prop, from, to) {
        return function (item) {
            return item[prop] >= from && item[prop] <= to;
        };
    };
```

And the view looks like this:

```
<label>Search from: <input ng-model="fromMinutes"></label>
<label>Search from: <input ng-model="toMinutes"></label>

    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" ng-repeat="student in AdminReportsWorksnaps.data | filter: AdminReportsWorksnaps.filterMinutes('totalMinutes', fromMinutes,toMinutes)">
                <td>{{ student.studentId }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.municipality }}</td>
                <td class="total success">{{ student.totalMinutes | number}}</td>
   </tr>
```

For some reason this is not working.
Well, If I Call filter like this: `filter: AdminReportsWorksnaps.filterMinutes('totalMinutes', 5000,6000)"` it works perfectly fine.. I just cant see how can I pass the input values from the textboxs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as `:` separated (Assuming you are using `controllerAs` pattern with `vm` alias)

```
ng-repeat="student in AdminReportsWorksnaps.data | filter: AdminReportsWorksnaps.filterMinutes: 'totalMinutes': fromMinutes: toMinutes"
```

So in above case you need to expect 4 parameter in a filter, 1st parameter would be `AdminReportsWorksnaps.data`, 2nd would be `totalMinutes`, 3rd `fromMinutes` & last would be `toMinutes` value

```
vm.filterMinutes = function (collection, prop, from, to) {
    //collection would have 
    console.log("AdminReportsWorksnaps.data", collection)
    console.log(prop, from, to);
    return (collection || []).filter(function (item) {
        return item[prop] >= from && item[prop] <= to;
    });
};
```

Comment: @HisniFazlija is your controller alias is `AdminReportsWorksnaps`?

Comment: yes and I tried with AdminReportsWorksnaps too but still does not seem like working

Comment: so I tried this: ng-repeat="student in AdminReportsWorksnaps.data | filter: AdminReportsWorksnaps.filterMinutes: 'totalMinutes': fromMinutes: toMinutes"

Comment: it prints the collection, and I can see the consoles updating. but the table is not filtering yet...

Comment: Now I get this error: VM19414:27 TypeError: collection.filter is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're using a `controllerAs`, so why don't use the controller alias for the models too :

```
<label>Search from: <input ng-model="AdminReportsWorksnaps.fromMinutes"></label>
<label>Search from: <input ng-model="AdminReportsWorksnaps.toMinutes"></label>

<tr style="cursor: pointer;" ng-repeat="student in AdminReportsWorksnaps.data | filter: AdminReportsWorksnaps.filterMinutes('totalMinutes', AdminReportsWorksnaps.fromMinutes, AdminReportsWorksnaps.toMinutes)">
    <td>{{ student.studentId }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.municipality }}</td>
    <td class="total success">{{ student.totalMinutes | number}}</td>
```

It should works like that.